# If row is equal to

Tags: php

I'm trying to get an error on my rating script, When somebody like an article the ip goes into the db. That goes fine, but I cant the ip from db equal to check ip. I need to receive a message which says `You already voted'

```
<?php
$user = new User();
if($user->isLoggedIn())
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        //Is it a proxy address
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    //The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
    $ip = ip2long($ip);
    $id = $row->id;

    // GET IP
    $q_50 = $db->query("SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM vote WHERE cID = '$id'") or die($db->error);
    if($row_50 = $q_50->fetch_object());
    if($row_50->ip === $ip)
    {
        echo 'You already voted';
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have any results and if you do what the ip value that is being returned is?

Comment: Try: "SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) as ip FROM vote WHERE cID = '$id'"

Comment: is cID a string or an int? if it is an int then remove the '

Comment: @xd6_ no.. he isn't return the ip.

Comment: Cant get the ip value returned.